# How is it possible to prove that Shanon entropy does not change applying any bijective function to X?

Tags: block-cipher, entropy, bijection

I was wondering how is it possible to mathematically prove that Shannon entropy does not change when applying any bijective function to X? For instance *H(X) = H(f(X))* assuming that **f** is invertible and X takes only finitely many possible values. In addition, I saw that this holds for block ciphers also but I could not figure out why?

Comment: The dupe was clearly a homework, now this.

Comment: Do not close (-voter). This is a philosophical question that has plagued the heart of crypto entropy for years on this forum.

Comment: I agree that this looks like homework and a clear duplicate of the other one, after all encryption maps restricted to a fixed key [as in other question]  are bijections. @PaulUszak you can ask a properly formulated question on this topic.